# "Function defined on/over the set A"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, mathematics, collocation

For the mathematically inclined fellows:

If *f* is a function whose domain is the set *A*,  do you say that *f* is defined on *A* or over *A*? Do both prepositions apply here or is the use of one of them decidedly wrong?

Comment: As a pure mathematician (albeit a junior one), I'd say that I've only ever seen functions described as being defined *on* some domain; if you look a bit more carefully at the examples for "defined over" provided in the answer below, you'll find that almost all of them actually refer to functions respecting some sort of structure on the domain and codomain.

Comment: These are not phrasal verbs. The verb here is *define*. *On* vs. *over* are prepositions (not propositions). I have retagged the question accordingly.

Comment: There is a [Wikiipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_(mathematics)) article which seems to indicate that the prepositions should be used in different cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, for mere functions I think **defined on** A is more common. A quick Google Books search* revealed examples of "defined over A", but that it's more common for a vector space or some more complex algebraic structure defined over A.

[Searching Google Books for **on**](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22f%20is%20defined%20on%22).

[Searching Google Books for **over**](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22f%20is%20defined%20over%22).

Comment: Yes, semantically _on_ is merely 2-D location, but _over_ implies a 3rd dimension with some locational variance. So _on the hill_ simply identifies the hill with the location, while _over the hill_ means either 'located on the other side of the hill' (Path variant) or 'located above the hill' (Flying Saucer variant). The most common mathematical uses I can recall all have some structure, if only an ordering relation, as in *defined over **R***.

Comment: Not only more common but absolutely normative and obligatory, at least in my (not particularly great) experience. As you say, "defined over *A*" refers to respecting a certain type of structure.

Comment: @JohnLawler I like your argument, but the conclusion is to use "over a set", because it is not a single element of the set but you "go over" the entire set, while defining the function.